# Flash movie only lasting 1 second?

Tags: flash, timeline

I'm working on an autorun CD, and the first step that I tried to do was to publish the file I have. I've made a small index for a catelog I'm working on, and when disc is put in the persons computer, what is suposed to happen is a flash made index comes up with options to view catelog or exit or go to website etc.  I just published the file, selected windows projector (exe) and published it. I found the file easily enough, but whenever I double click to open it, the screen for the index flashes once and then closes. I've never used Flash before, so I'm not sure why its doing this.

The only idea that I possibly have is that there is an issue with the timeline. I dont really know how to use timelines. The only thign that is supposed to really move in the index is a line of scrolling text at the top (which I edited within the actual animation itself so nothing shows up for duration on the main timeline, but the scrolling is supposed to last for 40 seconds). When I test it in Flash it works fine, the screen comes up, text scrolls over and over, and it stays open.

Right now my timeline looks like this:
[timeline](http://i74.photobucket.com/albums/i266/nanashiwolf/timeline.jpg)

so if anyone has any advice please let me know. Very very new to flash (opened the program just 2 days ago for the first time) and though I've been trying to read up on it and look at tutorials, a lot of it is still confusing to me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I almost sure you have `stop();` somewhere in those actions. I'm not experienced with  windows projector, but my guess is that when your movie play all your frames, it's just close itself. If you put  `stop();` first of your actions, it should help.

**update**

I just try create project and publish it as win projector. It doesn't go blank or close itself after playing first frame. So it's something else.

Comment: yes. it's as3 command, it just stop your program on current frame, all your action will still work, you will just stay in current frame, as you have only one frame, this should work for you

Comment: I just tried putting that stop script in the Actions of each layer, and then published it to see if it would work, but it still only lasts 1 second. Is the stop script supposed to go on a frame in the timeline? I used to have an Action layer, but I deleted it. Should I put it back? I feel bad asking these, but I'm quite a novice.

Comment: If you mean that you used to have a layer called actions, then that doesn't matter.  The naming of the layers is just a guide for you in the IDE, and is not used at runtime.  If that layer had a frame showing a little `a` symbol and you deleted that, then you may have deleted code that was required.

Comment: It didnt, only when I had assigned actions to it, but I prefered to have the desired actions on the desired layers, so I just ended up deleting the layer. I am going to try and go back to another tutorial I had seen, because the movie is still only lasting for 1 sec despite having a stop code in the layers. But if you have any other ideas, I'm very open to suggestions!